# how can I add a condition in php to detect that a session has ended?

Tags: php, session, logout

I created a page in php to log in users.
But once I logged out, if I type a restricted page in the browser I'm able to see it, even if I have logged out.

I have this code at the beginning of the page, any ideas? :) Thanks

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

?>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104205/php-how-to-detect-is-a-session-id-is-dead-or-alive Does this help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you're calling `session_destroy();` when logging out.

Also, you dont need

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
?>
```

in every page. This should just be in the login page. For every other page, it should be :

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    //Redirect to login Page
} else {
    //User is logged in. Display relevant content. 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_start` always when you need to work with session.

Before `session_start` no SESSION exists.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are a great way to control whether or not a user is logged in. A simple, yet insecure way would be to simply write a cookie "loggedin" upon successful login, and delete it upon logout.

More complex cookie login/logout logic could instead store a large, random string that is tracked in the database upon login. Upon logout, the database deletes the random string used for the cookie value, and the cookie is also deleted. This way, even if someone stole the cookie and tried to re-use it, upon page generation, it would check the status of that random string, and deny access to the page.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you did not destroy the session.
To do this, you must create a link to a page where clicking on 'logout' will lead to that page where you must invoke `session_destroy()`. For example, `<a href="path_to_your_page.php">Logout</a>`
And in your page, you run this:

```
 <?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @begueradj, yes I have on a different page a logout code... is the following:  `<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();
}
$_SESSION['username'] = "";
$_SESSION['username'] = NULL;

unset($_SESSION['username']);

session_destroy();

header("Location: ../index.php")

?>`  but if click back I get back to page with no problems